# Ubuntu Core and printer access

Tags: printing, ubuntu-core

Testing Kiosk installations/configurations on Ubuntu Core.

Can a snap gain access to an attached printer on Ubuntu Core installation directly or via any means?

Answer (score 0):

for USB printers your snap can use the raw-usb interface to gain access to /dev/usb/lp0 ... if you use an x86 based architecture you also have the printing-stack-snap (only available for x86 for some reason) that can give you a full cups stack on core.